# Reading an Excel file with empty fields

Tags: c#, excel

Am using a windows service written in c# to read and excel file. Some fields in the excel sheet can be empty. I encounter an error message when am reading the excel sheet at the point where the column is blank. The column is a DateTime field.

"SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM."

This is my code;

```
if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(dRow[3])) 
    {
         n.RBank_operator_date = DateTime.Parse(dRow[3].ToString().TrimEnd('"'));
    }
```

Comment: How are you reading the Excel file?  Try checking `dRow[3]` to see if it is null or perhaps string.Empty rather than DBNull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you just need to do this.

```
if (dRow[3] != null) 
{
     n.RBank_operator_date = DateTime.Parse(dRow[3].ToString().TrimEnd('"'));
}
```

DBNull is used when working with a database.